# How to give rank on datetime column group by another column with userid in it

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, rank

My columns are ID, User_created_date and Customer city
while user_created_date is in 2023-01-01 00:01:05+05:30 format
now I wanted to know when did the first user was created based on each city and give rank to them based on city

I tried first sort -> groupby and then rank but doesn't gives me desire output

Comment: So you want to know which users are the first in each city, is that correct? What do you mean "give rank to them based on city"? Ordering them by lexicographic order of the city they are in? Additionally, could you add your dataframe definition and initialisation in your question? This would allow us to test more easily.

Comment: Yes about the users you are right
About the rank means if city name Mumbai had 1st user created then the rank would be 1 and if New York had user created a minute after then New York would be assigned to 2

Comment: So you need to get the first users of each city and then sort them to get the cities order?

Comment: yes you got it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain a defined rank:

```py
import pandas as pd


if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        "ID": ["ID1", "ID2", "ID3"],
        "date": ["2016-6-10 20:30:0", "2016-7-1 19:45:30", "2013-10-12 4:5:1"],
        "city": ["New York", "Boston", "New York"]
    })
    df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S")

    print(df.groupby("city").min()["date"].rank(ascending=True))
```

This outputs

```
city
Boston      2.0
New York    1.0
Name: date, dtype: float64
```

Here, we grouped by city, then minimized over the date, then ranked over the values obtained in ascending order.